# Custom Uicells in UIviewController giving error

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, custom-cell

I am trying to display a custom TableView on a UIViewController but am getting an error "UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:"

I had connected the TableView to datasource and delegate.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Custom";

    Custom *cell = (Custom *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {

        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"Custom" owner:self options:nil];

         for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
        {

            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[Custom class]])
            {
                cell = (Custom *) currentObject;
                 break;
            } 
        }  
     }

     cell.textLabel.text =[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
[image]

---

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface VocaTableCell : UITableViewCell 
{
    UILabel *vocaLabel;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *vocaLabel;

@end
```

---

```
#import "VocaTableCell.h"


@implementation VocaTableCell
@synthesize vocaLabel;

- (void)dealloc {
    [vocaLabel release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Your code some wrong. below code refer plz. I've corrected.

Below code refer Befoe, Are you correctly make a customTableCell? below list check plz.

There are several ways to create about custtomTablecell.

My manner is very popular.

1. CustomTabelCell of File's Owner should be a **NSObject**. 
   (Very Important Default is Maybe UITableCell. You Must be a change File's Owner NSObject(NSObject mean is id type!))
2. CustomTableCell link a Object Class a your CustomTableCell Class.
3. Referencing Outlets link Not File's Owner, must be Your Directly link a CustomTableCell.

---

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Custom";

    Custom *cell = (Custom *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell)
    {
        UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"Custom" bundle:nil];
        NSArray *arr = [nib instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil];
        cell = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text =[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not returning the created cell at the end of the method. Add 'return cell;' at the end and the error shall disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the return statement? And is Custom a subclass of UITableViewCell?